# how i can to create nested childs from array of elements?

Tags: javascript

This is the given array:

```
array = [{number : 1 , name : 'one' , child : [] },{number : 2, name : 'two' , child : []},{number : 3 , name : 'three' , child : []}]
```

How to create nested child objects in JavaScript from this array?

```
nested = [
 {
  number : 1,
  name : 'one',
  child : [
   {
    number : 2,
    name : 'two',
    child : [{
     number : 3,
     name : 'three',
     child : []
      }
     ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

i try to solve this but i cant do this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [`array.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) method to achieve your result.

Here's how you can do it:

```js
const array = [
  { number: 1, name: 'one', child: [] },
  { number: 2, name: 'two', child: [] },
  { number: 3, name: 'three', child: [] }
];

const nested = array.reduceRight((a, b) => {
  b.child.push(a);
  return b;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(nested, null, 2));
```

> [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) The third argument enables pretty printing and sets the spacing

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to solve this problem.

Here's how you can do it:

```
const nested = array.reduceRight((a, b) => ({
  ...b,
  child: [{...a}]
})
)
```

I hope this answer can help you even a little.